# Python OPC-UA call method with array input argument

Tags: python, methods, opc-ua

I am very new to OPC UA, so please excuse if this is a very basic question.

I want to call a method with two input arguments. The input arguments are described as follows:
[image: Input arguments]

What I have tried is this:

```
evse = client.get_node("ns=6;s=::EVSE")
set_default = client.get_node("ns=6;s=::EVSE:SetDefault")
res = evse.call_method(set_default, 1, 20)
```

Which yields this error:

```
BadInvalidArgument: "One or more arguments are invalid."(BadInvalidArgument)
```

If I replace the last line by this

```
res = evse.call_method(set_default, [1, 20])
```

I get this error:

```
BadArgumentsMissing: "The client did not specify all of the input arguments for the method."(BadArgumentsMissing)
```

When I call the method manually from UaExpert, it works fine.
Can somebody give me a hint how to proceed?

Edit:
These are the argument structures expanded:

[image: Argument structures]

Comment: What are the expected datatypes of each argument? Expand the Argument structures in the UaExpert screenshot and add it to your question.

Comment: The first is uint16 and the second is float. I added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: They were able to help me over at [Github](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/python-opcua/discussions/1320). This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Does the Python library automatically cast the method arguments for you?

Maybe you're just not providing values of the correct datatype in your first attempt; try this instead:

```py
res = evse.call_method(set_default, 1, 20.0)
```

Or look into the documentation or source code to see if this is required of you. I also don't know if there's a special unsigned "wrapper" class you would need to use for the first argument if the library doesn't do this casting for you.

Comment: I found it out now. Indeed, the method requires a special class as input argument. I added a comment pointing to the solution below my initial question. Thank you for your help.